# Confused by too many URLs for WebServiceClient

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws, webservice-client

I have a class similar to the following

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;

@WebServiceClient(
    name = "BlahName",
    targetNamespace = "http://my.domain.com/service",
    wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/BlahName?wsdl" 
)
public class BlahClient extends Service {
    public BlahClient(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }
}
```

I'm confused about the various URLs (or URL look-a-likes), they seem to be highly redundant to me:

- There is a wsdlLocation in the annotation and in the 1st constructor parameter.
- There is a "service name" in the second constructor parameter
- And a namesspace in the annotation

I kind of understand the one wsdlLocation, but why do I have two? Which one is used.

Why does the serviceName contain an URL, I thought that is basically the same as the wsdlLocation modulo the '?wsdl' part.

And what is the "Namespace" used for?